# Does this syntax avoid watchers?

Tags: angularjs

I am using bindonce in a not documented way, so i am not sure it avoid watchers.

The thing is i need to put a character next to my expression, so i can't use `bo-text` (since it doesn't interpret expressionsn like `#{{User.position}}`).

**I am using it this way:**

```
<div bindonce ng-repeat="User in Users">
  <span>#{{User.position}}</span>
</div>
```

**instead**

```
<div bindonce ng-repeat="User in Users">
  <span bo-text="User.position"></span>
</div>
```

Do te both example avoid watchers ?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a watcher?

Comment: Because i can have hundreds of entries and they will stay static so i don't want to loose performance uselessly. I rode that around 200 watchers you start to impact the UI experience.